Unable to test a component which is wrapped in a styled component
I'm writting a test case to my component. As below
render(<DetailsPage/>);
expect(screen.byTestId("details-wrapper-select")).toBeInDocument();

Then I'm getting Below error:

console.error
Error
Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')] at
at reportException (/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)

Also

135 | render()
at partRule (node_modules/styled-components/src/utils/isStaticRules.js:6:16)
at e.warnTooManyClasses [as generateAndInjectStyles) (node_modules/styled-components/src/models/Com node_modules/styled-components/src/models/StyledComponent.js:90:5)
at $as ( at WrappedStyledComponent (node_modules/styled-components/src/models/StyledComponent.js:128:44)

So what I did is to debug is,
return (
        <DetailsWrapper>
           // commented everthing in between...
        </DetailsWrapper>
)

Still getting the same error.
Then,
return (
    <div data-testid="details-wrapper-select">hello</div> 
)

Test case passed here...
And then...
return (
        <DetailsWrapper>
            <div data-testid="details-wrapper-select">hello</div>
        </DetailsWrapper>
)

Still got same error. DetailsWrapper is just a Styled.div with out any props.

I believe you need to wrap those components with the styled-components theme provider in the tests

I agree with Avi, on wrapping your components with a provider, but the error may also originate from styled-components. Since your test passes when using a plain div, the issue is within DetailsWrapper. Ensure styled-components is correctly installed and up-to-date. The problem might be a specific style or a bug in the library version.
